# Implementing HTML book-like pagination

Tags: android, html, xml, pagination, epub

I found a solution to this somewhat at [HTML book-like pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636052/html-book-like-pagination?tab=active#tab-top) I am not being able to implement the same on the android using eclipse 3.6. The code I am using is as follows:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {     
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {          
       // Column Count is just the number of 'screens' of text. Add one for partial 'screens'         
       int columnCount = Math.floor(view.getHeight() / view.getWidth())+1;          

       // Must be expressed as a percentage. If not set then the WebView will not stretch to give the desired effect.         
       int columnWidth = columnCount * 100;          
       String js = "var d = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];" +              "d.style.WebkitColumnCount=" + columnCount + ";" +              "d.style.WebkitColumnWidth='" + columnWidth + "%';";         

       mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" + js + "})()");     
     } 
   });       

   mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chapter.xml");
```

The LogCat shows that the width and height displayed to me are 0. Am I putting it at the wrong place? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: welcome on stackoverflow, please use the select the code and hit the `{}` button, and don't me affraid to use some returns and tabs :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this solution and it worked for me. Try Nacho L solution on this [HTML book-like pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636052/html-book-like-pagination)?