# android webview overflow cannot be disabled

Tags: android, webview, overflow

[image: remote debug screencast]

I have a local page in android webview, pages's `html` and `body` both has `width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;` , and the `#result-popup-wrap` has the following css:

```
#result-popup-wrap {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 245px;
background: #fbfbfb;
border-top: 1px solid #dcd9d5;
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

but, as you see, when I scroll to bottom of the page, I can see the `#result-popup-wrap`, which should not be visible.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Just for anyone who are suffering the same problem.

ADD `position:relative`  to  the `<body>` tag.

Apparently, this is a bug of WebView, on both Android and iOS. On chrome of PC version, page renders OK without `body{position:relative;}`, but in WebView, you can scroll the entire page, including the 'hidden' `#result-popup-wrap`.

[click here to see demo](http://jsbin.com/kupumu/1/edit)  , **pay attention to the UPPER comment in css**

Answer (score 2):

you can set `body{position:fixed;top:0}` to the body.

Comment: Great! This is the ONLY solution to disable vertical scroll on webview on android. Thanks a lot!!!