# Text pagination in Android

Tags: android, text, pagination, textview

How to make text pagination in `Android` `TextView`? How to divide long text into pages?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to create an ebook viewer?

Comment: yes, something like ebook viewer.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837840/paginating-text-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

There's been a fair amount of discussion on SO on this topic, in my opinion there isn't a good solution for this yet.

Here's the solution I ended up using: [HTML book-like pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636052/html-book-like-pagination). Take a look at Nacho L's implementation of the accepted answer. It worked tolerably well in Android as well... though it is a little buggy, in my experience, if there are images or long strings in the html content.

Maybe it'd be worth the time to write a new View for this.