# Android - Paging issue of WebView.capturePicture() result

Tags: android, printing, webkit, export

I've making a module export HTML to another data format on Android.

When searching about WebView on Android, I turn into the solution exporting to Picture because the WebView supports this job by method:

```
WebView.capturePicture()
```

The captured picutre is fine & full of the web pages I've tried (except some very long websites and I've not concerned on this yet)

But now, the problem I'm facing is that the whole exported picture usually long and is not paging. If it is printed out, the page breaking is not controlled, text lines (at that time, they are image data) at the bottom or top of a page may be broken in the middle.

So, question now is that Is there a way to insert the page break before or after the exporting to gain some more acceptable page breaking results?

1. Before exporting:
   i.  set options for capturePicture or use some tricks like that?
   ii. insert page break into web content (HTML)?
2. After exporting: use some image processing library on Android to break result into pages?

Comment: I've solved out the problem, please follow [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636052/html-book-like-pagination?tab=active#tab-top