# creating new Print android application

Tags: android

I want to create my own print application for android. I don't know from where to start? any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am able to get the content of current webview and store it in internal storage as a .jpg picture , but i want to print that content and not store it.

Comment: what do you mean by print? send it to a Printer?

Comment: Print basically means i want to print it on a paper, like how when you say Ctrl+p in windows and u can print a hard copy of a document. I want to have same kind of implement in my activity on click of one button called "print", but i don't want user to have access to go to settings. That means user cannot chose what printer he wants to print on , or what size paper he want, or orientation of paper. I just want to print the content of the webview on paper.

Comment: A good start would be implementing some kind of printer protocol

Comment: what do you mean by print protocol

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

start searching for print images from Android, because you can make screenshots( a bit tricky, but you can) or search for text printing.

A few links may help:

[Integration Steps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android)

[Web view printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248709/android-paging-issue-of-webview-capturepicture-result)

Comment: i am trying to print capture image from webview and print it. I also dont want user to have any access to change any settings regarding printing. So when they hit a button called "print", the content od current webview should be printed.

Comment: my printing means i want a copy on a paper. That is i am able to get a screen shot of webview as ..jpg image, but the question is i want to print it on paper. I don't want users to have access on what printer you want to print on, what size of paper to print on , or what orientation to print in. So no access to change any setting, just a button click and the page will be printed for them.

Comment: @user1932345 looool, if you will hit the button "Fly" do you think your Android will fly? :) - sometimes I want a button with "make the software" -provided a few links for you

Comment: i know how to capture pic from webview and also i tries  something here: http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/android-journal/iprintphoto#comments But again the problem is the bottom arrow over there takes me to settings which i don't want user to go inside.