# Paginating HTML document for printing with WebKit-based browsers

Tags: javascript, html, printing, webkit, phantomjs

**Internet Explorer has [Print Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) engine**, where I can use `DEVICERECT` element to represent a physical page, then use `LAYOUTRECT` element as a rectangular view to flow the HTML document through into the page and drive the pagination. That prevents lines from being cut-off in the middle between adjacent pages. This mechanism is described in details [here](http://www.google.com/patents/US7647553).

**Does WebKit provide a similar feature?** Specifically, does PhantomJS do? I'm looking for anything that would allow to paginate an existing HTML document which doesn't have predefined page-breaks, and view it paginated as a new transformed HTML or PDF document, without lines being cut-off in middle.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636052/html-book-like-pagination

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The browser engine should take care of everything and you can aid it using a stylesheet for `media="print"`.

For example to force page breaks such that every heading of level 1 or 2 (`<h1>` or `<h2>`) is placed at the beginning of a new page use [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before):

```
h1, h2 { page-break-before:always; }
```

In Chrome, IE & Opera you can control [widows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/widows) and [orphans](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/orphans), but it hasn't landed in WebKit yet, so for now you could use

```
p { page-break-inside: avoid;  }
```

to avoid page breaks inside paragraphs.

You can even control margins for [first, left and right pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) separately.

Phantom's `render()` uses stylesheets for print media if the output is a pdf file. [`rasterize.js`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) example looks like a ready to use printing solution.

Comment: +1. Media queries and css3 page-break rules are how I handle PDF and printing when using wkpdftohtml. It tends to work more reliably in recent browsers/engines and with certain types of elements but if you control the rendering engine version and aren't relying on the client that's not such an issue. They are really useful rules so it's a shame browsers have dragged their heels on support.

Answer (score 2):

This function working fine.

```
$(function () {
    $("#print-button").on("click", function () {
        var table = $("#table1"),
            tableWidth = table.outerWidth(),
            pageWidth = 600,
            pageCount = Math.ceil(tableWidth / pageWidth),
            printWrap = $("<div></div>").insertAfter(table),
            i,
            printPage;
        for (i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
            printPage = $("<div></div>").css({
                "overflow": "hidden",
                "width": pageWidth,
                "page-break-before": i === 0 ? "auto" : "always"
            }).appendTo(printWrap);
            table.clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo(printPage).css({
                "position": "relative",
                "left": -i * pageWidth
            });
        }
        table.hide();
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

This will split entire table into multiple sections...

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkUYv/)

---

Code taken from [this article](http://salman-w.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/print-wide-html-tables.html) and [this page](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/04/printing-wide-html-tables.html).