# How to remove extra space at the bottom of the HTML Page

Tags: javascript, android, html, pagination, epub

I'm currently splitting HTML pages into multiple pages based on the screen size using the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165698/4402462) provided by Nacho.

The solution successfully split the pages into multiple pages but there is extra space at the bottom of every page.

[image]

As you can see from the vertical scroll bar in the image, only part of the white spaces are visible to you but there is more if you scroll to the bottom.

How can I remove this?

The extra space to the content is in the ratio of 4:1. The extra space is not because of any other views in the view group. The layout looks like

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <WebView />
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you have set a **specific size** for your View Group Layout and you set either your web view to follow it, quick fix would be in your **web view add**:

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

That should set the height to the size of the content.

Cheers.

Comment: Previously, Both Width and Height for ConstraintLayout is set to `match parent` and Webview is set to `0dp`, I've changed Webview's width and height to `wrap_content` but the issue still remains.