# How to show HTML file in webview with Page by page division like a Reader?

Tags: java, android, xml

In my android project, I have saved one HTML file inside my application. Now, from an Activity class I am using a **webView** to show the contents of this **HTML file**. This html file contains very long amount of text showing as a paragraph within **paragraph** tag.

So, in **webView** I can read the text by **scrolling vertically**. But I need a suggestion to show the entire content, page by page like a reader adjusting the mobile screen. More clearly, i don't want user to scroll vertically, rather user will swap right or left to move from one page to another.

**Here's the Layout xml file code-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewPagerActivity">


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview_reader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And here's my Activity class code-**

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview_reader);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("file://"+ViewPagerActivity.this.getFilesDir()+"/a.html");

    }
}
```

Here's the output of the app-

[image]]

I also tried to show the **webview** in **Pageview** but it also didn't work. So, I want this entire html page to divide the character by adjusting the mobile screen and show them page by page like a reader. So, it would be very nice if someone help me out this problem with coding example.

Comment: [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096884/3290339) might be useful.

Comment: But how can I use PagedTextView inside webView?

Comment: Of course you can't. I suggest to use `PagedTextView` instead, if applicable, w.r.t the `html` you have, I mean `Html.fromHtml(string)` has a limited `html / css` tags support

Comment: Or you might look at this old post: [HTML book-like pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3636052/3290339)

Comment: One more note. Since you're using the `html` file locally stored, why not storing the text in a `txt` file instead? For reading text from a text file located in assets you might look at the Github sample app.