# how to view epub documents as pages according to printed counterpart?

Tags: epub

In popular desktop ebook viewers like calibre, FBreader or Cool Reader, I'm missing a feature to show ebooks in the same pagination as their printed counterparts. Some people (here, too) claim that epub does not have a page concept (e.g. at [how to implement 'page break' in epub reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808652/how-to-implement-page-break-in-epub-reader)).

But this is not true. From http://www.idpf.org/accessibility/guidelines/content/xhtml/pagenum.php:
"If an ebook is produced from the same workflow as a print document, print pagination markers should be retained in the document. These markers benefit readers in mixed print/digital environments, such as a classroom, as the page numbers allow a common point of reference between the two editions." and from its FAQ-section: "Do page numbers really matter anymore? - Yes. Despite the assertions of the futurists and technophiles, print still reigns supreme. As a result, anyone in a mixed print/digital environment — using an assistive technology or not — needs a way synchronize electronic and print content."

I tested several ebook viewers with two different documents that contain page break tags, but they did not break up into pages (or I'm missing a preference option). Any help, infos are highly appreciated.

Comment: The assertion "EPUB has no concept of page" is correct. The fact that there is a markup mechanism to indicate the points where the publication breaks into pages is NOT equivalent to say that EPUB has the concept of page.

Answer (score -1):

You can force page break with CSS and the property `page-break-after=always` but is not the best page layout for an ebook. For example add a class to your `epub:type="pagebreak"` label with that style.

```
<span epub:type="pagebreak" id="page23" class="pagenumber">23</span>

.pagenumber { /* other styles*/ page-break-after=always !important; }
```